# Not working cursor:pointer in Google Chrome browser for option tag ?

Tags: css, google-chrome

how to give the cursor as pointer in option tag? For now it's working good in firefox and safari browsers but not working in chrome. can any one give any suggestion on this.

```
<style>
select option{
cursor:hand;
cursor:pointer;
}
</style>

<select>
<option>On mouse over need Hand symbol</option>
<option>11111111111111</option>
<option>22222222222222</option>
<option>33333333333333</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

If Chrome does not support it, you won't be able to do it.

The only way would be to use some Javascript (or CSS) custom dropdowns, which is not worth for only changing the cursor.